# Orbit space of $[0,1]^n$ when symmetric group acts on $[0,1]$ is $n-$ simplex.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$[0,1]^n/S_n\simeq \Delta ^n$

The group $S_n$ acts as follows: $\sigma (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_{\sigma 1}, x_{\sigma 2},\cdots, x_{\sigma n}).$ for every $\sigma\in S_n, \forall x_i\in [0,1]$.

$\Delta^n=\{(x_0,x_1,...,x_n): x_i\in [0,1], \sum x_i=1\}.$

It is clear that $\Delta^n\simeq \{(x_1,...,x_n): x_i\in [0,1], \sum x_i\le 1\}$, and that the set on RHS is $\simeq \{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n): x_i\in [0,1], x_1\le x_2\le\cdots\le x_n\}=X$, say.

Now define $f: [0,1]^n\to X$ as usual, i.e., take $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in [0,1]^n$ and $f$ maps it to $(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_n}),$ where $k_i\in \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $x_{k_i}\le x_{k_{i+1}}$ for all $i\le n-1$. Let's denote by $q$ the quotient map $[0,1]^n\to [0,1]^n/S_n$. If $f$ is continuous, then $g$ is induced and the following diagram commutes:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} [0,1]^n @>q>> [0,1]^n/S_n \\ @.     {_{\rlap{f}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(40deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{5em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVgV\\  @. X \end{CD}$$

On the fibres of $f$, $q$ is constant and on the fibres of $q$, $f$ is constant. So $g$ is a bijection, and since $[0,1]^n$ is compact and $X$ is Hausdorff, $f$ is a closed map, hence a quotient map. So by the property of quotient maps, $g$ is a homeomorphism.

My question is: how can we show that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: $X$ is Hausdorff because it is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\sigma \in S_n$, let $F_\sigma = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in [0,1]^n \mid x_{\sigma(1)} \le x_{\sigma(2)} \le \dots \le x_{\sigma(n)}\}$. Then each $F_\sigma$ is closed and since every the coordinates of each $x \in [0,1]^n$ can be ordered in some way, $x \in F_\sigma$ for some $\sigma$. In other words, $[0, 1]^n = \bigcup_{\sigma \in S_n} F_\sigma$.

Now, $f$ restricted to each $F_\sigma$ is the permutation $\sigma$, in particular $f|F_\sigma$ is continuous. Since $\{F_\sigma\}$ is a finite collection of closed sets, $f$ is continuous by the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm afraid I don't understand 1) how to write $[0,1]^n$ as the union of $F_\sigma$ as you suggest and 2) how to apply pasting lemma here? Can you please supply more details? Thanks.

Comment: Added some words, but not sure which steps need clarification. Are you familiar with the pasting lemma?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's much clearer to me now. Yes, I am familiar with the pasting lemma. In the last para, don't you mean $f$ restricted to $F_\sigma$ is $\sigma$? I think so because for $(x_1,..., x_n)\in F_\sigma, f(x_1,..., x_n)= (x_{\sigma 1},..., x_{\sigma n})= \sigma (x_1,..., x_n)$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.